# Is it possible to cast from super class object to subclass when the objects are not dynamically allocated (not pointers)?

Tags: c++

I have a global function within a namespace and this function is a helper function that will create objects and return them. However the return type is of the parent class, but the actual object returned is a subclass of the parent. It is then up to the user to cast it returned "parent" object to the appropriate subclass. I thought this is what polymorphism was about but I am not able to cast the returned object to a subclass. For example:

```
class Parent {...};

class ChildOne : public Parent {...};
class ChildTwo : public Parent {...};

Parent my_function(int x) {
    if(x) {
        return ChildOne();
    }
    else {
        return ChildTwo();
    }
};

int main() {
    // The statement below is giving me an error (no matching function call...)
    ChildOne my_child = (ChildOne)my_function(1);
}
```

Comment: Read about **object slicing in C++**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as it is written in [NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164079/341970),

Since you asked in comment what you could do instead, this is how you can achieve (more or less) what you want in C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Parent { 
  public:
    virtual ~Parent() { }
};

class ChildOne : public Parent {
  public:
    void say_hello() { cout << "Hello from ChildOne!" << endl; }
};

class ChildTwo : public Parent { };

unique_ptr<Parent> my_function(int x) {

    if(x) {
        return unique_ptr<Parent>{ new ChildOne() };
    }
    else {
        return unique_ptr<Parent>{ new ChildTwo() };
    }
}

int main() {

    auto parent = my_function(1);

    if (ChildOne* my_child = dynamic_cast<ChildOne*>(parent.get())) {
        my_child->say_hello();
    }
}
```

However, I would revise my code in such a way that the downcast (cast from parent to child) is not need. There are certain situations where it is needed or unavoidable but most of the time it is a sign of design flaw.

Comment: Thank you, I briefly looked at smart pointers. But I opted to just return a normal pointer instead. I think it is much more straight forward.

Comment: @Akash Yes, it is easier now but you sooner or later you will have ownership problems and memory leaks. It's ultimately your choice but if I were you, I would take this opportunity to learn smart pointers. In any case, good luck!

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot cast the object returned by `my_function` to a subclass of `Parent`.

Since:

```
Parent my_function(int x) {
```

returns the object by value, it always returns an object of class `Parent`, and never a subclass. This is due to [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

For a discussion, see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Comment: Is there a better way to do what I wanted here? It isn't possible to pass by reference right? Is dynamic allocation and casting the pointer the only way?